# Build Tensorflow >2.4.* with c++11 compatibility

Tags: c++, tensorflow, c++11, c++14, tensorflow2.0

The idea is to build Tensorflow >2.4.* (*tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so* & *tensorflow:install_headers*) to use it in a C++ project compiled in C++11 standard.

After creating a Docker container on Ubuntu:16.04 with the rights [dependencies](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) and using `gcc 7.5.0-3`. I managed to successfully compile the library using the following command: `bazel build --config=opt --config=cuda --config=monolithic --cxxopt="-D_GLIBCXX_USE_CXX11_ABI=0" //tensorflow:libtensorflow_cc.so //tensorflow:install_headers`

However, the compiled library seems to be compiled with c++14 standard because it raises the following issue

```
    include/tensorflow/core/framework/tensor_types.h:176:25: error: use of ‘auto’ in lambda parameter declaration only available with ‘-std=c++14’ or ‘-std=gnu++14’
  176 |     auto all = [](const auto&... bool_vals) {
      |                         ^~~~
```

Changing my application from `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 11)` to `set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)` also confirm that TensorFlow has been successfully compiled and is working.
Changing C++ standard in my application is not an option yet.

After some checks, It seems that [TensorFlow is built with C++14 by **default**](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/v2.8.0/.bazelrc#L319).
I tried to manually change the value of c++ from `c++14` to `c++11` without success.
I also tried to compile TensorFlow using the library [TensorFlow_CC](https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc) from FloopCZ because it [set the C++ standard for building and linking the library](https://github.com/FloopCZ/tensorflow_cc/blob/v2.7.0/tensorflow_cc/CMakeLists.txt#L14). But it also fails.

Issues on Github did not help me to solve my problem.

Any idea to compile Tensorflow and be able to use it in c++11 application?
Is it even possible to run TensorFlow >2.4 on C++11?

Comment: Tensorflow is *written in C++14*. You cannot compile it with C++11 unless you manually remove all C++14 features from its source. I guess this is not an option. Then the only way to compile your application is to avoid `#include`ing tensorflow headers in any file compiled with C++11. You can write a thin shim layer that directly calls Tensorflow and compile it with C++14, and compile the rest of your application with C++11. There should be no problem in mixing the versions like that.

Comment: @n.1.8e9-where's-my-sharem. Can you make an answer out of your comment?